# cryptic bash variable

Tags: bash

I encountered this cryptic bit of code which I believe contains some form of variable expansion.

`echo "Usage: ${0##*/} [-f] [-u user] [--] "`

Is the dollar sign followed by the brace-enclosed string equivalent to the bash variable $0? If so, why would one use the former as opposed to the latter? Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: This might get a better response on http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${variable}` is regular parameter expansion. The braces can be used to delimit a variable name when expanding in the middle of another string. For example, if you wanted to expand `$variablefoo`, the shell would have no way to know where the variable name ends. By using `${variable}foo` instead, the shell knows exactly what you mean.

The braces also allow for a various other operations to be made during expansion. Your example above deletes what the expression matches, from the left. If given a string such as a path `/a/b/c`, it will return `c`. This is effectively equivalent to what `basename` does, but parameter expansion can be more convenient and readable in some situations.

There are various basic string operations that can be performed with parameter expansion. Being a built in operation, they are generally better performing than sed or awk when doing simple tasks.

If you are into shell scripting, I suggest you read [this guide](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) on the bash hackers wiki.

Comment: Good explanation mkaito. Here's a couple links that also explain it well, each in their own style. The "Chopping strings like a pro" section here [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-bash/index.html) and of course The Linux Documentation Project website [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF)

Answer (score 2):

It uses [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to strip the directory from `$0`.